# Flutter: Merge two images to create a single image in Dart

Tags: image, user-interface, flutter, dart, merge

I want to merge two images and show them as a single image. Is it possible to do this in flutter by not doing natively?

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Can you please provide example if possible.

Comment: Use [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) paint them in canvas any resolution as you want, combine them horizontally, vertically as you wish.

Comment: If you found a solution for your own question, submitted it as an answer and mark it as correct.